# Extracting part of a large SQL dump

Tags: linux, grep, head

Is there a way to chain commands like grep and head together to extract a portion of a file?

The problem is that somewhere in my .sql file I have an old data that I need to compare to new data and I don't know what line I need to tell Head to start at. But I only need to go for maybe 10 lines...its a small table.

I am looking for something that does

```
Find `database`.`tablename` | head next 20 lines to new file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-A` to specify how many lines after a match you want printed.

```
grep -A 20 '`database`.`tablename`' dump.sql
```

This will of course also include the match, and you can pipe that to a viewer. There's no need for `head` here.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a few more results than I needed but `head` cleaned it up. Thank you very much, 10000 times better than waiting to download, open, scroll, copy, paste!